# What is the purpose of empty "remotes" folders in the .git folder?

Tags: git

There are empty folders in `myrepo/.git/refs/remotes`. What is their purpose?

They seem to map to past used remote names. If so, what would be the affect of deleting them?

If I do not delete them, what would be the affect to adding a remote with the same name as one of the folders? Would that cause any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ProGit on "Git Internals"](http://progit.org/book/ch9-3.html) mentions:

> If you add a remote and push to it, Git stores the value you last pushed to that remote for each branch in the refs/remotes directory.
>
> For instance, you can add a remote called `origin` and push your `master` branch to it:

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:schacon/simplegit-progit.git
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 11, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 716 bytes, done.
Total 7 (delta 2), reused 4 (delta 1)
To git@github.com:schacon/simplegit-progit.git
   a11bef0..ca82a6d  master -> master
```

> Then, you can see what the `master` branch on the `origin` remote was the last time you communicated with the server, by checking the `refs/remotes/origin/master` file:

```
$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master 
ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949
```

> **Remote references differ from branches (`refs/heads` references) mainly in that they can’t be checked out**.
> **Git moves them around as bookmarks to the last known state of where those branches were on those servers**.

I wouldn't recommend adding any subfolder in what is the internal structure of the git database, but removing its content should be safe (it would only means the next `git fetch` would refetch everything from the declared remotes).
As the [Pro-Git chapter on the refspecs](http://progit.org/book/ch9-5.html) mentions:

> In the default case that is automatically written by a `git remote add` command, Git fetches all the references under `refs/heads/` on the server and writes them to `refs/remotes/origin/` locally.
> So, if there is a `master` branch on the server, you can access the log of that branch locally via:

```
$ git log origin/master
$ git log remotes/origin/master
$ git log refs/remotes/origin/master
```

> They’re all equivalent, because Git expands each of them to refs/remotes/origin/master.